# How can I multiply large, denser scipy.sparse matrices in a memory-efficient manner if I wish to ignore small values?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra

I have two, large, `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` matrices. I cannot multiply them because I run out of memory. The sparsity structure is ruined after the dot product because of a lot of extremely small, non-zero values. It is possible to rescue the sparsity structure by setting these numbers to zero and calling `eliminate_zeros` but that will not work as I run out of memory.

If I know I wish to ignore values below a certain threshold ahead of time, how can I make use of that information? Currently, the only approach I've come up with that works, but is super slow, is:

```py
chunksize=10000
numiter = A.shape[0]//chunksize
CS=[]
for i in range(numiter):
    C = A[i*chunksize:(i+1)*chunksize].dot(B)
    C.data[C.data<0.1]=0
    C.eliminate_zeros()
    CS.append(C)
C=sp.sparse.hstack(CS)
```

I compute the dot product 10,000 rows at a time and zero out values less than some threshold (in this case 0.1). That way I can construct the full matrix without running out of memory. However, this approach is really slow. I'd appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: When you try to elimate zeros on the whole thing, what's the error?  In other words, can you pin down where memory error is occuring?

Comment: `sparse.hstack` converts the inputs to `coo` format, and combines their attributes.  Those are then used to create a `coo` matrix.  That's a safe, but relatively slow process.

Comment: Another observation.  The `A[...]` slicing is done with matrix multiplication.  It makes a sparse extractor matrix (1s for the desired rows), and multiplies.

Comment: The speed bottleneck is taking the dot product of the matrix subsets.